# AttributeError: NoneType

Tags: raster, pyqgis, masking, qgis-python-console

I have this code I use in the QGIS Python console. I used it a few days ago and it worked, but I tried using it again and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, 
in runcode exec(code, self.locals) File "<input>", line 1, 
in <module> File "<string>", line 33, 
in <module> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 136, 
in runAndLoadResults for param in alg.parameterDefinitions(): 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parameterDefinitions'
```

I checked all my definitions, and I see they are correct. How can I possibly resolve this?

```
# Import necessary modules
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsRasterLayer
import processing

# Initialize QGIS application 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Set path to input raster layer
file_dir = 'D:/WDF_03012023'
mask_dir = 'D:/WDF_03012023/masks'
Date = '030123' #to always edit depending on Date involved
Ring_num = '1aRuta' #always change this to what is after the R in the file name

# Construct the Ring-specific names and paths
Ring_name = f'030123_R{Ring_num}' #always change date here to the date working on
mask_name = f'mask_{Ring_name[7:]}_{Date}'
Ring = file_dir + '/' + Ring_name + '.tif'
mask = mask_dir + '/' + mask_name + '.tif'

# Load the input raster layer
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(mask)

# Polygonize the raster layer
polygonized_layer = processing.runAndLoadResults(
    "gdal:polygonize",
    {
        'INPUT': raster_layer,
        'BAND': 1,
        'FIELD': 'DN',
        'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS': False,
        'EXTRA': '',
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'  # Let QGIS use the specified temporary directory
    }
)

# Fix geometries of the polygonized layer
fixed_geometries = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:fixgeometries", {'INPUT': polygonized_layer['OUTPUT'], 'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

# Clip the input raster based on the mask
clipped_ring = processing.runAndLoadResults(
    "gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer",
    {
        'INPUT': Ring,
        'MASK': fixed_geometries['OUTPUT'],
        'SOURCE_CRS': None,
        'TARGET_CRS': None,
        'NODATA': None,
        'ALPHA_BAND': False,
        'CROP_TO_CUTLINE': True,
        'KEEP_RESOLUTION': True,
        'SET_RESOLUTION': False,
        'X_RESOLUTION': None,
        'Y_RESOLUTION': None,
        'MULTITHREADING': False,
        'OPTIONS': '',
        'DATA_TYPE': 0,
        'EXTRA': '',
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'  
    }
)
```

Comment: Is there more to the error message? There's no mention of `parameterDefinitions` in your code so it must be a problem from something called by it, which should be revealed by the full traceback error...

Comment: " I use in the QGIS Python console" - isn't this a standalone PyQGIS script that should be run standalone from the shell console, not the QGIS Python console? Maybe it works both ways but it looks like a standalone script to me...

Comment: @Spacedman thanks for your response, I currently have issues using it as a standalone (I would resolve that soon), hence I use it in the QGIS console.

Not sure if I can put the traceback error here, but here it is:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 33, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 136, in runAndLoadResults
    for param in alg.parameterDefinitions():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parameterDefinitions'

**Here is why I looked at the parameterDefinitions.**

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification. This is particularly true for error text.

Comment: print(raster_layer.isValid()) gives True?

Comment: I've added your traceback to the question. Now we can see that `alg` is `None` and where its been called from, which helps.

Comment: If using the Python console you are already inside a running QgsApplication. So you should remove or comment out the 2 lines which `setPrefixPath` and `initQgis`. They will cause you problems.

Comment: @BenW You should put your comment as answer since this looks like the issue:  override of the qgsapplication paths making gdal unavailable

Comment: Thank you all for your response. @BenW, I have commented out those lines but still the same error. I ran the code on a separate computer and it works. I guess I might need to uninstall my QGIS and reinstall a new.